# Shortcuts "Ctrl+." and "Ctrl+," not responding

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to take me to the "next" usage of a member/variable.
All of a sudden today, they stopped, and started taking me to a random "unused" member.
Does the "Next/previous" have a context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Toolbar:
Next Annotation(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>)->Check "Occurrences" only